# Extracting certain rows from a csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

I have a large CSV file with around 1500 rows and 8 columns. I want to create a new CSV file with reduced number of records i.e with only certain rows from the first CSV. I have the required row nos in a list. How to extract the required rows without affecting the main CSV file. I want to do this using python.

Comment: "I have the required row nos in a list". What exactly does this mean?

Comment: I have the indicies of the required rows form the original CSV.

Comment: Exactly how many CSV files are involved? You start out saying you have a large one that you want to change, and then go on to mention something about a first one and later a main one -- where do these others come in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `numpy.loadtxt`:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt('yourfile.csv', delimiter=',')
row = data[3] # fourth row e.g.
```

edit:
Incorporating the above:

```
rowlist = [0, 5, 99]

with open('output.txt', w) as out:
    for rowindex in rowlist:
        out.write(data[rowindex])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use csv.DictReader or csv.reader to read the file, create the output csv with the header that you prefer using extrasaction='ignore'. If you want to keep all the columns, just copy the field headers from the input to the output specification. I am just giving a more general case. When you output the file to a new csv file, it will only output the columns that you specified in the output header. All other columns will be dropped. Your output loop will use the row indicators that you specify. Row 1 of the output file will be the new header.

```
for rowindex in rowlist:
  outfile.writerow(indata[rowindex])
```